# What degree of k bias is acceptable in ECDSA?

Tags: dsa, modular-arithmetic, nonce, rfc6979

So there’s [LadderLeak](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/615).

[RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979.html) produces uniformly random nonce $k$.

There are other techniques, such as hash-to-curve standard ([draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16 section 5](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16.html#name-hashing-to-a-finite-field)), which allows to produce uniformly random scalars. They mention it’s OK to use 128 additional bits of entropy, e.g 48-byte hash to produce 32-byte private key, when targeting 128-bit security level. The bias is still there but it’s reduced to 2^-64 or so. They mention it in the context of private keys.

How safe could this technique be when used in $k$ generation, instead of RFC6979?

Comment: "hash-to-curve standard, which allows to produce uniformly random scalars"; actually, a hash-to-curve operation produces a point $H$ that no one knows the discrete log to (that is, no one knows the solution for $H=kG$).  That's not what ECDSA needs.

Comment: @poncho you’re wrong. The standard has methods for hashing to fields. See section 5. Hashing to ec point is irrelevant in this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that the hash-to-curve draft talked about hashing to things other than curves...

Comment: [Not all RFCs are standards](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1796); and the [draft RFC](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16.html) considered starts with "Intended Status: Informational", meaning it's not intended to become a standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preliminary: no matter how good the method to generate the nonce $k$ in [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) is, it will *not* prevent [LadderLeak](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/615), which is a side-channel attack independent on bias in the *generation* of $k$.

The technique in RFC [draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16 section 5](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16.html#name-hashing-to-a-finite-field) can be adapted to generation of nonce $k$ in ECDSA instead of what [RFC6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979.html) recommends. The general sketch being that we generate nonce $k$ in range $[1,n)$, deterministically from the ECDSA private key† and hash of message being signed, where $n$ is the curve's order.

The RFC's method generates $m$ values in $[0,p)$ (by their notation), thus we'd want‡ to set $m=1\,$, $p=n-1$, and add $1$ to the one generated integer in $[0,p)$ to obtain nonce $k$ in $[1,n)$. We can do this by inserting a $+1$ as step 7 in the [algorithm](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-16.html#name-hash_to_field-implementatio), making it $e_j=(\operatorname {OS2IP}(\mathrm{tv})\bmod p)+1$.

There's a certificational issue, that we can just ignore: the RFC's technique is intended to generate a field element, thus is stated for prime $p$, which would not be the case for $p=n-1$. However the RFC's technique happens to work unmodified for any $p>0$; it just does not generate a field element (it's stated goal).

Critically, whatever implementation of the RFC's techniques must not create a side channel (on the private key, or on the generated nonce $k$), which could allow an attack.

Regarding the acceptable bias in the generated nonce $k$ in ECDSA: rest assured there is no danger whatsoever in using $\mathtt{L}=48$ byte in the RFC when generating a nonce $k$ of 32 bytes (corresponding to security parameter of 128 bit in the RFC).

- If we can't distinguish the generated nonce $k$ from random (which is the claim of the RFC), it's good enough for ECDSA without having to even think about what attack we consider (argument: whatever attack on ECDSA based on the bias on nonce $k$ would allow to build a distinguisher invalidating the RFC's security claim).
- Actual adversaries are limited in the number of signatures they can obtain. Even $2^{64}$ is wildly unrealistic (especially if we consider the fact they must be for the same public/private key pair). Thus we could do with 64-bit security, and 128 is way overkill.

---

† No relation to the nonce $k$ designated in the question as *"32-byte private key"*.

‡ Alternatively we could as well set $p=n$, and discount the probability that the nonce generated is zero by accident. It's however sensible to test against that at some point, and that must be in a side-channel proof way, including but not limited to constant time. If this condition triggers, either something is broken or we are under attack, and a sensible reaction is to zeroize all sensitive material, perhaps the private key.